# Getting only images in our UIWebView from any website.

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimage

How can we only get images in our `UIWebView` from any website like Google Image Gallery?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you just want to show only images in the `UIWebView` and ignore all other markup?

Comment: what do you want to do? I am getting confused too.

Comment: You should specify more clearly what it is you want. Did you try someothing already? What happened?

Comment: Also, bits like "I am getting confused!! plz help me!!" is pure noise which adds nothing to your question.

Comment: yes i tried something already!! i am getting whole web page in my UIWebView but dont know how to get only images in my UIWebView although i know each image have its unique url.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the UIWebView to load a URL which is a direct link to an image, e.g. http://www.someserver.com/image.png